# Finding the bounding parallelogram for an x,y point

Tags: geometry

I have a series of points arranged on a grid of parallelograms.  I know the width and height of the grid, and so I know the boundary of each parallelogram.

Given an arbitrary $x$, $y$ point, I want to find the vertices that bound that point (or, pragmatically, just the lower left hand vertex).

In the example below, I know that vertex $n$ is at $x=(n\mod 4)/4$, $y=n/12$.  With the $x,y$ point shown, I want to find vertex #$2$, because $x,y$ is within the parallelogram bounded by vertices $2,3,6,7.$  (Don't worry about edge conditions -- I can handle those.)

I'm pretty sure there's a closed form for this using floor and mod, but my brain appears unwilling to produce it.
[image: Find the bounding parallelogram]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I found the "aha" in coordinate transformation.  If we define

```
x' = x
y' = y - x/3
```

then the parallelograms become squares.  And then it's trivial to find the index of the lower left vertex:

```
i = floor(x*4)/4 + 4 * floor(y'/3);
```